# Upload images to firebase from ReactNative

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am new to firebase and am having a little trouble uploading pictures to `firebase.storage`.

In my app I have an image and when I console.log it I get this:

```
file:///Users/waltermonecke/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B38A76A…6E2-5EE0F4B38878/Documents/images/F6DFDD32-A741-446B-B035-F8407197421C.jpg
```

So basically a reference to the `.jpg` image. Now I want to upload it and this is my code thus far:

```
let img = job.photo1.uri;
console.log(img) // See above

let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`/jobs/${currentUser.uid}`);
storageRef.put(img);
```

I thought this would have been enough but I am clearly missing something since I get this error message:

```
Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

storageRef.put accept Blob rather than string. React native don't have built in method to convert image file into Blob , so you can use [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) library to achieve this.

```
 Blob.build(img, {
      type: "image/png;"
 }).then(blob => {
     firebase
     .storage()
     .ref(`/jobs/${currentUser.uid}`)
     .put(blob, { contentType: "image/png" })
     .then(snapshot => {
         // Done upload
         blob.close();
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I did not see a `.build`  method in the Blob object.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what library you are using for your firebase integration... Assuming `react-native-firebase`, this should work:

```
firebase
 .storage()
 .ref(`/jobs/${currentUser.uid}`)
 .putFile(img)
 .on(
   'state_changed',
   (snapshot) => {
     console.log(snapshot);
   },
   err => {
     console.error(err)
   },
   (uploadedFile) => {
     console.log(uploadedFile)
   }
 );
```

Comment: I am using firebase, I tried the putFile method. However, it appears it is not a valid method call.

`_firebase2.default.storage(...).ref(...).putFile is not a function`

Comment: Are you using this package?   https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase  Thats the one I was referencing originally.... I know it isn't a full answer, but I've used it with ease.